# Check if all object entities are equal using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this `List<Employees>` with 2 attributes for example:

```
Long ID 
String Name
```

I want to have a stream that check if all employees in that list has the same ID. How can I do that in stream?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Just a tip on how to do it, check how many distinct (based on `ID`) elements there are in the stream.

Comment: Why should all employees have the same ID? Isn’t the purpose of an ID to be different?